# How to change alias of table for Active::Record include option( default alias : table_name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I am facing a similar issue: https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/issues/30 when I use include in my query which is returned by searchlogic. This issue was there since 3 years. I hope someone might have know the fix. And also I didn't find implementation of include (source). 
Any guide on the issue will be helpful. Is there any way to change table alias for different joins???

Thank you.

Comment: Any solution found on this issue?

Answer (score -2):

Here you can find description of includes method
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations